# Wpf setting style to dynamically created label not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, label, code-behind

I'm working on a scorekeeping app in WPF for Darts, and part of it is to display the score, which the player has thrown. I'm trying to output it on the window using dynamically created labels like this:

```
Label throwLabel = new Label();
throwLabel.Content = score.ToString();
throwLabel.Style = Resources["BoardStats"] as Style;
throws.Children.Add(throwLabel);
```

Where throws is a Stack Panel and BoardStats is a style defined in app XAML. The problem is that when the label appears on the window, it doesn't have the style I have given it in the code above. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you checked that `Resources["BoardStats"] as Style` doesn't return null?

Comment: Please post the XAML where you have the `BoardStats` defined. I agree with @KooKiz, check what that line is returning. Also, didn't you want to use `FindResource("BoardStats") as Style` instead?

Comment: If you would use `MvvM` then you would just add the `score` to your collection either observable or not,on your `View Model` and in your UI you could use `List View` with defined `Item Template` and all of this would go away and your `Style` would get applied without single line of code behind. Just saying ...

Comment: `FindResource()` worked, thanks!